# Bundler with rbenv version pathfile issue

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, bundler, rbenv

So I am using rbenv to set my ruby version (for the specific project I'm working on this is 2.1.1).  The issue is that bundler is unable to detect this change.  I even tried to set the version in my gemfile:

```
source "https://my-proxy-address"
ruby "2.1.1"
gem 'fileutils'
gem 'json'
gem 'chef-api'
```

However this then causes the exact error message as seen [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) at the end of the tutorial:

```
username@hostname:~/Desktop/working-bundler-env$ rbenv version
2.1.1 (set by /Users/username/.rbenv/version)
username@hostname:~/Desktop/working-bundler-env$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin15.0]
username@hostname:~/Desktop/working-bundler-env$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1
```

[The tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) has the solution to the issue (edit a pathfile), however they dont say what file to change. What file do I change?

```
$ rbenv
rbenv 1.0.0
Usage: rbenv <command> [<args>]

Some useful rbenv commands are:
   commands    List all available rbenv commands
   local       Set or show the local application-specific Ruby version
   global      Set or show the global Ruby version
   shell       Set or show the shell-specific Ruby version
   install     Install a Ruby version using ruby-build
   uninstall   Uninstall a specific Ruby version
   rehash      Rehash rbenv shims (run this after installing executables)
   version     Show the current Ruby version and its origin
   versions    List all Ruby versions available to rbenv
   which       Display the full path to an executable
   whence      List all Ruby versions that contain the given executable

See `rbenv help <command>' for information on a specific command.
For full documentation, see: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#readme

$ which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

Comment: Did you try `rbenv rehash` ?

Comment: I tried it no change

Comment: Can you show your the $PATH variable value (`echo $PATH`) and also output of the `rbenv` command?

Comment: Theres no output for `rbenv rehash` and heres my $PATH `/Users/$MYUSER/.rbenv/shims:/Users/$MYUSER/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: The command is just `rbenv` without "rehash"

Comment: I can't paste the full output, but I assume you are looking for my rbenv version: `rbenv 1.0.0`

Comment: Please add it into your question it's important. And also I need `which bundle` output.

Comment: `which bundle` should return `/Users/your-login/.rbenv/shims/bundle` path or something like that. Could you check if you have `$HOME/.rbenv/shims/bundle` file?

Comment: Nope I don't have any file under `~/.rbenv/shims/bundle`

Comment: You should work in this way, it must be there. Do you have any ruby versions installed(`rbenv versions`)? Could you check if you have `~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/bundle` path?

Comment: Yes I have 2.1.1 installed with rbenv, but `bundle` is not in `~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/` and it is also not present in any other ruby versions I have under `~/.rbenv/versions/`

Comment: Maybe I haven't installed it then. Can you try `gem install bundler` in your `~/Desktop/working-bundler-env` folder.

Comment: Yea I've been trying various attempts at completely uninstalling bundler then reinstalling it with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I noticed that when I ran `gem bundle install` the version was `1.13.3`.  After running `sudo find / -name bundle` I found two file locations that included that version number.

```
/Users/myusername/.gems/gems/bundler-1.13.3/exe/bundle
/Users/myusername/.gems/gems/bundler-1.13.3/lib/bundler/man/bundle
```

After attempting to run `/Users/myusername/.gems/gems/bundler-1.13.3/exe/bundle install` it works perfectly.  So I just made an alias in my `~/.bash_profile` that overwrote the incorrect bundle command.

```
alias bundle=/Users/alexcohen/.gems/gems/bundler-1.13.3/exe/bundle
```

The only side effect of this gem (for better or worse) is that it creates `.bundle` and `path` directories in the directory where I run `bundle install` where the gems are downloaded into.

I still have to investigate why this is happening, but I think that the `bundle` command in my macs terminal was referencing some type of broken bundler gem or file somewhere in my system.